# How to crawl a page search results when post/head request returns code 200

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, http-post

I need to get all the cruise info from that page http://www.pocruises.com/find-and-book/cruise-search-results/
Problem is that the button that calls that page has no `href` to send the request to and when i send it to the link above i get `<Response [200]>`. How to i get all the cruise info in `json` or `xml`? Do i have to scrape the page entry by entry? This is what i did so far:

```
page = session.get("http://www.pocruises.com/find-and-book/cruise-search-results/")
print(page)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to get all the links in the page.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.pocruises.com/find-and-book/cruise-search-results/'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    print link.get('href')
```

But if you need to get more info, I suggest you to use Scrapy https://scrapy.org/